# MS Access relationships - I have an issue designing my database efficiently

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-design

So I have several tables currently, but my issue at the moment has to do with one table in particular. This table is supposed to show the "path" a specific product through several machines. This is the table below:

PathID   |   Step1   |   Step2   |   Step3

So basically I have a machine identifier in each step column that is linked to a machine table. However, not every process goes through three machines; some go through more, some through less, and not often in the same order. I feel like this will create a LOT of redundant inputting here, and I wanted some opinions on how to properly structure this.

Thanks!

Comment: Since a path can be long or short (just like some peoples legs), the number of steps can vary greatly. I would have a table for products, a table for each machine (i.e. a "Step") and a table that relates the two (let's call this 'Path') with a sequence number. Thus your example results in three rows in the "Path" table and each row contains the Product ID and the proper Machine Id, and the Step #.

Comment: Please pick between [mysql] and [ms-access].  Or explain why you tagged with both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table with three columns (maybe more):  `PathID`, `ordinal`, and `Step`.  The `ordinal` keeps track of the order, and replaces the suffix on `Step`.  The `PRIMARY KEY` would probably be `(PathID, ordinal)`.

Comment: Using multiple columns for a primary key is not something that is allowed in MS Access (MySQL is also tagged but the title specifies Access). I think a separate primary key is required (autonumber will probably do).

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth multi column primary keys are certainly allowed in Access.